# MYSQL: Invalid JSON text: "Invalid escape character in string."

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, mysql2

I'm trying to insert a JSON object into a MySQL JSON column and I'm getting: `Invalid JSON text: "Invalid escape character in string."`

The offending character is the `\n` in this part of the object:

`"summary":"Summary of Qualifications:\nAccomplished and results-driven General Business Director with a consistent track record."`

I've tried JSON.stringify, JSON_OBJECT, JSON_QUOTE, and my most recent attempts included:

`summary.replace("\n", "\\n")` and variations on replacing the existing escape characters with proper? escape characters.

I'm using Node, Express and JawsDB if that may have any bearing.

EDIT: Here's the actual insert code:

```
const fields = '(myField)';
const values = `('${JSON.stringify(field.contents || {})}')`;
db.query('INSERT INTO mydb ' + fields + ' VALUES ' + values,
    err => { 
        if (err) {
            console.log(values);
            throw(err) ;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: instead i would say stringfy the json and put it in a varchar column of mysql and then at time of retrival just parse the string using json.parse

Comment: What leads you to believe `\n` is the problem?  How are you actually doing the insert?  Placeholders? (e.g. `VALUES(?)`)?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot just added my actual code.. I am using placeholders here. Also it tells me the offending line # of the object. I suppose it could be the colon in front of the \n instead.

Comment: Thanks @RahulSingh that's a good alternative approach if I can't get this working, although I'd like to take advantage of the optimizations that a JSON column offers over varchar.

Comment: You are **not** using placeholders.  A placeholder is a literal `?` inside `VALUES()`.  Use this:  `db.query('INSERT INTO mydb ' + fields + ' VALUES (?)', [ JSON.stringify(field.contents || {}) ], err ...` You should never concatenate string literals into queries.  It is unsafe and (as you now see) error-prone.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot feel free to add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're building your query with string concatenation, which is a dangerous (SQL injection) and error-prone (unexpected/incorrect string-escaping, problems with embedded quote `'` marks in strings) practice.

Your query, rewritten to use placeholders, should work correctly:

```
db.query('INSERT INTO mydb ' + fields + ' VALUES (?)', [ JSON.stringify(field.contents || {}) ], err ...
```

The underlying problem is that in a MySQL literal string expression, `\n` doesn't mean `\` + `n`, it means ASCII 0x10 (newline).  In JSON, a newline character inside a quoted string is invalid -- a newline in a JSON string is serialized as two characters, `\` + `n` -- and the fact that MySQL's string parser recognizes this pattern to mean the same thing it means in JSON is essentially a coincidence, though this convention is common.  Here, it bites you because you're intending to send two characters to MySQL but the parser interprets it.

You could have <strike>worked</strike> hacked around this by doubling up the `\` to `\\` in the string, which the server would interpret as a literal `\` + `n`, but allowing the database driver module to handle any necessary quoting and escaping for you is the more correct approach.

Comment: Multiple statement queries are disabled by default to prevent SQLi.

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries